# Running an individual test from a specification

Tags: unit-testing, scala, specs2

Is there a way to run a specific test from a Specs 2 `Specification`? e.g. If I have the following:

```
class FooSpec extends Specification {
  "foo" should {
    "bar" in {
      // ...
    }

    "baz" in {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to have a way to run only `FooSpec > "foo" > "bar"` (using some arbitrary notation here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ex` argument from sbt to run a specific example:

```
sbt> test-only *FooSpec* -- ex bar
```

You can also mix-in the `org.specs2.mutable.Tags` trait and include a specific tag:

```
sbt> test-only *FooSpec* -- include investigate

class FooSpec extends Specification with Tags {
  "foo" should {
    tag("investigate")
    "bar" in {
      // ...
    }
    "baz" in {
       // ...
     }
   }
}
```

You can also just re-run the previously failed examples, whatever they are

```
sbt> test-only *FooSpec* -- was x
```

Finally, in the next 2.0 release (or using the latest 1.15-SNAPSHOT), you will be able to create a `script.Specification` and use "auto-numbered example groups":

```
import specification._

/**
 * This kind of specification has a strict separation between the text 
 * and the example code
 */ 
class FooSpec extends script.Specification with Groups { def is = s2"""
  This is a specification for FOO

  First of all, it must do foo
  + with bar
  + with baz

  """ 

  "foo" - new group {
    eg := "bar" must beOk
    eg := "baz" must beOk
  }
}

// execute all the examples in the first group
sbt> test-only *FooSpec* -- include g1

// execute the first example in the first group
sbt> test-only *FooSpec* -- include g1.e1
```

There is however no way to specify, with a mutable Specification, that you want to run the example `"foo" / "bar"`. This might be a feature to add in the future.

Comment: how about doing that in scala IDE ?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the namespace of tests to be executed, but AFAIK there's no way to run a specific test from the `sbt console`. You can do something like:

`sbt test:compile "test-only FooSpec.*"`, which runs the tests only from the `FooSpec` namespace, but this selection is namespace based and not even that works properly. This is the selection mechanism, but it somehow fails and always runs the entire set of tests found in your project.

**Update**

From the [official documentation](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Testing):

`test-only`

The test-only task accepts a whitespace separated list of test names to run. For example:

```
test-only org.example.MyTest1 org.example.MyTest2
```

It supports wildcards as well:

```
test-only org.example.*Slow org.example.MyTest1
```

Comment: This allows me to go to the level of `FooSpec` but not deeper.